# How to quickly find and substring multible items from string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I'm rather new to C++ and I'm struggling with the following problem:
I'm parsing syslog messages from iptables. Every message looks like:
`192.168.1.1:20200:Dec 11 15:20:36 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=250`
And I need to quickly (since new messages are coming very fast) parse the string to get SRC, DST and LEN.
If it was a simple program, I'd use `std::find` to find index of `STR` substring, then in a loop add every next char to an array until I encounter a whitespace. Then I'd do the same for `DST` and `LEN`.
For example,

```
std::string x = "15:30:20 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=15.15.15.15 LEN=255";
std::string substr;

std::cout << "Original string: \"" << x << "\"" << std::endl;

// Below "magic number" 4 means length of "SRC=" string 
// which is the same for "DST=" and "LEN="    

// For SRC
auto npos = x.find("SRC");
if (npos != std::string::npos) {
    substr = x.substr(npos + 4, x.find(" ", npos) - (npos+4));
    std::cout << "SRC: " << substr << std::endl;
}

// For DST
npos = x.find("DST");
if (npos != std::string::npos) {
    substr = x.substr(npos + 4, x.find(" ", npos) - (npos + 4));
    std::cout << "DST: " << substr << std::endl;
}

// For LEN
npos = x.find("LEN");
if (npos != std::string::npos) {
    substr = x.substr(npos + 4, x.find('\0', npos) - (npos + 4));
    std::cout << "LEN: " << substr << std::endl;
}
```

However, in my situation, I need to do this really quickly, ideally in one iteration.
Could you please give me some advice on this?

Comment: A little warning about regular expressions: There's a saying that goes something like "You have one problem. You solve it using regular expressions. Now you have *two* problems". While regular expressions can be a powerful tool, it's also very advanced and definitely non-trivial. Regular expressions are easy to get wrong, and should be used only as a very last effort. Especially by beginners, and often even intermediate level programmers.

Comment: Do you have evidence that your program is too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format is fixed and verified (you can accept undefined behavior as soon as the input string doesn't contain exactly the expected characters), then you might squeeze out some performance by writing larger parts by hand and skip the string termination tests that will be part of all standard functions.

```
// buf_ptr will be updated to point to the first character after the " SRC=x.x.x.x" sequence
unsigned long GetSRC(const char*& buf_ptr)
{
    // Don't search like this unless you have a trusted input format that's guaranteed to contain " SRC="!!!
    while (*buf_ptr != ' ' ||
        *(buf_ptr + 1) != 'S' ||
        *(buf_ptr + 2) != 'R' ||
        *(buf_ptr + 3) != 'C' ||
        *(buf_ptr + 4) != '=') 
    {
        ++buf_ptr;
    }
    buf_ptr += 5;
    char* next;

    long part = std::strtol(buf_ptr, &next, 10);
    // part is now the first number of the IP. Depending on your requirements you may want to extract the string instead
    unsigned long result = (unsigned long)part << 24;

    // Don't use 'next + 1' like this unless you have a trusted input format!!!
    part = std::strtol(next + 1, &next, 10);
    // part is now the second number of the IP. Depending on your requirements ...
    result |= (unsigned long)part << 16;

    part = std::strtol(next + 1, &next, 10);
    // part is now the third number of the IP. Depending on your requirements ...
    result |= (unsigned long)part << 8;

    part = std::strtol(next + 1, &next, 10);
    // part is now the fourth number of the IP. Depending on your requirements ...
    result |= (unsigned long)part;

    // update the buf_ptr so searching for the next information ( DST=x.x.x.x) starts at the end of the currently parsed parts
    buf_ptr = next;
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
const char* x_str = x.c_str();
unsigned long srcIP = GetSRC(x_str);
// now x_str will point to " DST=15.15.15.15 LEN=255" for further processing

std::cout << "SRC=" << (srcIP >> 24) << "." << ((srcIP >> 16) & 0xff) << "." << ((srcIP >> 8) & 0xff) << "." << (srcIP & 0xff) << std::endl;
```

Note I decided to write the whole extracted source IP into a single 32 bit unsigned. You can decide on a completely different storage model if you want.

Even if you can't be optimistic about your format, using a pointer that is updated whenever a part is processed and continuing with the remaining string instead of starting at 0 might be a good idea to improve performance.

Ofcourse, I suppose your `std::cout << ...` lines are just for development testing, because otherwise all micro optimization becomes useless anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I'm sorry, but I'll accept the other answer (with regex) for simplicity, but I should tell you that I'd try your code as well and I appreciate your effort very much! Thanks again.

Comment: @Groosha I'm wondering, did you performance test your previous solution from the question and compare it to the regex solution? I'm interested whether you really gain any performance from regex or just the beauty of maintainable code.

Comment: Since I'm not even amateur c++ coder (I mostly write Python code), my assumptions were purely logical: in my code, each substr is a new object (`string`) which takes time to create and each `find` requires to scan through the whole string (= iterate) each time. So I guess my own code (in question) is stupid and slow. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Groosha You should really test it... I created some benchmark with a vector of 100000 strings to be processed and stored into a result object. I got the following results (I replaced the output by storing into an internal result object): My code: `0.024sec` your code: `0.044sec`, regex code: `0.617sec` so basically, the regex solution would be like 14 times slower than the code that you started with. Maybe I did something wrong in the way I used the regex in detail, but you should really race your horses if you care for performance!

Comment: hmm..that's a **huge** difference. I should definitely look deeper into it. Thanks again. Could you please share your "benchmark" code? Maybe on pastebin?

Comment: @Groosha I had to transform each version a bit to make it work completely, but I hope I did it in a way that reflects the original codes: https://onlinegdb.com/BkfH9M3bz (grek40) https://onlinegdb.com/Bk0n5G3bz (question) https://onlinegdb.com/Hyeqsf3WG (regex)

Comment: @Groosha I'm kindof interested whether you stayed with the regex approach or something different in the end. After all you explicitely stated performance requirements in the question ;)

Comment: Sorry, I was on sick leave and competely forgot to comment here. Your code is really faster than regex approach Less readable, but I've documented it carefully. Thanks again!

Comment: @Groosha as discussed, your own code is actually pretty fast as well. So you can shift a bit towards readability and robustness without losing much performance. Just remember that Regex is more about coding performance and compactness and less about over the top execution speed.

Answer (score 1):

"quickly, ideally in one iteration" - in reality, the speed of your program does not depend on the number of loops that are *visible* in your source code. Especially regex'es are a very good way to hide multiple nested loops.

Your solution is actually pretty good. It doesn't waste much time prior to finding "SRC", and doesn't search further than necessary to retrieve the IP address. Sure, when searching for `"SRC" it has a false positive on the first "S" of "Sep", but that is solved by the next compare. If you know for certain that the first occurrence of "SRC" is somewhere in column 20, you might save just a tiny bit of speed by skipping those first 20 characters. (Check your logs, I can't tell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::regex`, e.g.:

```
std::string x = "15:30:20 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=15.15.15.15 LEN=255";

std::regex const r(R"(SRC=(\S+) DST=(\S+) LEN=(\S+))");
std::smatch matches;
if(regex_search(x, matches, r)) {
    std::cout << "SRC " << matches.str(1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "DST " << matches.str(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "LEN " << matches.str(3) << '\n';
}
```

Note that `matches.str(idx)` creates a new string with the match. Using `matches[idx]` you can get the iterators to the sub-string without creating a new string.